# How to animate font size without text reordering, when `text_size=self.size`

Tags: python, animation, kivy, font-size, text-size

I need to display some text and later on animate its font size. The text must not exceed the size of its widget so I use `text_size: self.size` (I don't mind the text exceeding its widget size during animation though)

[image]

The problem is that animation of the font size forces the text to reorder, which is ugly (red circle in image got there during animation)

[image]

I would prefer it *did* exceed temporarily that size, instead.

How can I achieve both the text not exceeding its widget's size, and during font-size animation to exceed that size (shown in image below)?

[image]

---

Code used:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv = """
<MyWidget>:
    text: 'long text...' * 5
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'middle'
    on_release: self.animate_function()
"""


Builder.load_string(kv)


class MyWidget(Button):

    def animate_function(self):
        initial_font_size = self.font_size
        anim = Animation(font_size=initial_font_size * 1.5, duration=2)
        anim += Animation(font_size=initial_font_size, duration=2)
        anim.start(self)


class MyButtonsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyButtonsApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could animate a stretching of the text instead of its font size. This would be slightly less graphically precise (like enlarging a small image looks blurry), but might be good enough depending on your parameters. It would also be *much* more performant; animating the font size requires re-rendering the texture each time.

I have a very simple example of using a Scale instruction for this, which you can find [here](https://github.com/inclement/kivy-finger-chooser/blob/master/player_chooser/playerchooser.kv#L37).

Comment: If i use `scale` in a widget which is a child of a `BoxLayout`, wouldn't it force other children in that `BoxLayout`  to change size as well?

Comment: You can use PushMatrix and PopMatrix to constrain where the Scale takes effect.

Comment: Since links can go bad, I included the code from your link in an answer below. It might be useful to visitors (that is, faster to use) if you include that code in your answer (no attribution required of course; it's your code after all). If you do, let me know so that I can delete my answer. (I didn't edit the code into your answer since it would be too substantial of a change)

Answer (score 0):

Using the code suggested by [inclement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2469283/inclement) I end up with the following code which behaves as described in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37174110/4230591):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


kv = """
<MyWidget>:
    text: 'long text...' * 5
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'middle'
    on_release: self.animate_function()

    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix:
        Scale:
            origin: self.x + 0.5*self.width, self.y + 0.5*self.height
            x: self.scale
            y: self.scale

    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix:
"""


Builder.load_string(kv)


class MyWidget(Button):
    scale = NumericProperty(1)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.initial_scale = self.scale

    def animate_function(self):

        anim = Animation(scale=self.initial_scale * 1.2, duration=.1)
        anim += Animation(scale=self.initial_scale, duration=.1)
        anim.start(self)


class MyButtonsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyButtonsApp().run()
```